# IIS7 returns 404 on some static files, not others

Tags: iis, http-status-code-404

I have a css file and a js file in a directory. The css file returns 200 OK while the js file returns 404 Not Found.

They have the same permissions. IUSR, IIS_IUSRS, Internet Guest Account all have (at least) Read.

Comment: What handlers and filters do you have running for the site, I've had a similar issue in the past where all requests were being handled by a http handler and it was returning 404 for extensions it didn't recognize even if the file was there and it had permissions to open it.

Comment: Turned out to be a very specific problem to our setup, an old Rewrite module was being used that took a regex of file types to rewrite for, and js was not included in the regex. I tried closing the answer but it won't let me.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and accept it. Include the troubleshooting steps as well. They may prove helpful to others in a similar conundrum.

Answer (score 4):

Add the file type to IIS MIME TYPES.
It wont serve unknown file types.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the file type to the IIS MIME Types worked for me. Fortunately for caveman-brains like mine, IIS let's you do this with the UI.

From the [MS website](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

> To use the UI
>
> 1. Open IIS Manager and navigate to the level you want to manage. For information about opening IIS Manager, see Open IIS Manager (IIS 7).
>      For information about navigating to locations in the UI, see
>      Navigation in IIS Manager (IIS 7).
> 2. In Features View, double-click MIME Types.
> 3. In the Actions pane, click Add.
> 4. In the Add MIME Type dialog box, type a file name extension in the File name extension text box. For example, type .xyz
> 5. Type a MIME type in the MIME type text box. For example, type 'application/octet-stream'