# IIS Hosted Project on Virtual Machine not resolving localhost for Scripts

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, virtual-machine

I have a Published ASP .NET MVC web project running in IIS within a VMWare Virtual Machine(Windows 7). I am able to log in to the VM and navigate across the application from within the VM itself, but all content files(JS, CSS) are returning a 404 error.

i.e : 'http://localhost/WebProject/Home/Index' loads fine, but, 'http://localhost/WebProject/Scripts/Home/IndexScript.js' within that page throws a 404 error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you can access IIS on your VMWare it means that your IIS works fine and VMWare too but there some settings which restrict access to some urls or url is wrong.

Are you sure that you have file at path **/Scripts/Home/IndexScript.js'**

If yes then check

[IIS not serving static content (css/js/images, etc) 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33279618/iis-not-serving-static-content-css-js-images-etc-404)

[IIS7 returns 404 on some static files, not others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818826/iis7-returns-404-on-some-static-files-not-others)